# Saving figure to pdf prints # instead of tabs in titles

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

if I create a plot with some tabs in the titles and try saving that to a local pdf file (via `print` function), I get some hashtags instead of tabs in the pdf. This does not occur in the visible figure.

For example, I plotted the residuals of an approximant to the runge function on a grid:

```
plot(g, f(g) - runge(g));
title(sprintf('residuals,\t max_x(s-f) = %.3f', max(f(g)-runge(g))));
```

Then after some axes manipulation (grid, boxes, etc..) I execute

```
h = gcf;
set(h,'Units','Inches');
pos = get(h,'Position');
set(h,'PaperPositionMode','Auto','PaperUnits','Inches','PaperSize',[pos(3), pos(4)])
print(h,'data/runge_example.pdf','-dpdf','-r200')
close(h)
```

Is somebody aware of that behaviour or better able to found that as already solved than I am?

EDIT: Same behaviour with `saveas` and saving to eps. This does **not** happen with `\n`

EDIT2: I'm using Matlab Version R2017b (9.3.0.7...)

Comment: I had some similar problems sometimes with formatting of some characters. My work around was export to EPS and convert EPS to PDF later. But same problems may appear in the last conversion too.

Comment: Same happens with `saveas`, when saving as eps... didn't worked as workaround unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried [`saveas´](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html)?

Comment: @Guto yes, see above

Comment: One thing. If you get the eps and open it as text. It is with a tab or a #? If a tab, the problem can be in the pdf side, not on the saving side. Maybe a missing driver/font of something alike. A comment, it takes a while find the text, and symbols written separately.

Comment: It is with a hashtag in the eps too...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165562/discussion-between-guto-and-nico-albers).

Answer (score 2):

So, after a long discussion we figured out that we have no idea of how to use tabs in matlab titles in combination with latex mode.

To clarify: use math environments and escape tex directives, otherwise it will throw an error.

so

```
sprintf('residuals,\t $max_x(\\vert s-f\\vert) = %.3f$', max(f(g)-runge(g))));
```

will give you a nice string:

```
residuals,   $max_x(\vert s-f\vert) = 0.264$
```

The problem is, that it *really* is a tab. And the matlab latex interpreter (don't know which one that uses, the system or an own) crashes on that. I copy-pasted that to a tex document and pdflatex ran fine on it (but not showing that much space unfortunately).

So, I came up with the following fix:

use the latex directive `\quad` or `\qquad`:

```
title(sprintf('residuals,\\quad $max_x(\\vert s-f\\vert) = %.3f$', max(abs(f(g)-runge(g)))));
```

This will give you more space than a normal space.

***EDIT***: For this to work you need the interpreter of matlab to be set to "latex" instead of the default "tex". Do this by changing the title to

```
title(title_string, 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```

or by setting (globally for that script)

```
set(groot, 'defaultTextInterpreter', 'latex')
```